# how to slice an item from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ionic-framework

Can someone please help me with some ionic code?
I have have an array of items displayed using `ngFor`. When a user click on a certain item, that item is then pushed to another page which have full description of the item and it have a complete button.
When a user clicks the complete button the item should be removed from the original array. I just don't know how to slice an array from a different component. Please help

Comment: show us what you have tried and what issue you are facing with code

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Please include the actual code that you need help with instead of just describing it.

Comment: in case you want only to slice item from your array you can do this 
    const indexToDelete = array.indexOf(item);
      array.splice(indexToDelete, 1);
so you have to keep the index of the clicked item with you to be able to splice it from the original array

Answer (score 0):

What I've understood is that you want to remove a certain item from an array. Is that correct?

In that case you can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) like in this example:

```
let myArray = [{ a: 'firts', b: 'foo' },
    { a: 'second', b: 'bar' },
    { a: 'third', b: 'baz' }];

// to remove the third item from the array do this:

// first argument is the index of the item to remove
// second argument is the number of items to remove
myArray.splice(2, 1);

console.log(myArray) // [{ a: 'firts', b: 'foo' }, { a: 'second', b: 'bar' }]
```